# ROS topics and Rviz not working for LiDAR gmapping (/map)

Tags: rviz, gmapping, mapping, lidar, tf

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B with Ubuntu 20.04 and ROS Noetic 1.16.0 and I'm trying to use Gmapping with the /map topping with my LiDAR (an EAI YDLIDAR X4 with its driver, I think Radar_Con_V1.3.5.). I have a folder for my LiDAR with the following files in the launch folder:

lidar_gmapping.launch:

```
<launch>
  <include file="$(find gmapping)/launch/slam_gmapping_pr2.launch" />

  <include file="$(find lidar)/launch/X4.launch" />

  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find lidar)/launch/mapping.rviz" />
</launch>
```

X4.launch:

```
<launch>
  <node name="ydlidar_lidar_publisher"  pkg="ydlidar_ros_driver"  type="ydlidar_ros_driver_node" output="screen" respawn="false" >
    <!-- string property -->
    <param name="port"         type="string" value="/dev/ydlidar"/>  
    <param name="frame_id"     type="string" value="laser"/>
    <param name="ignore_array"     type="string" value=""/>

    <!-- int property -->
    <param name="baudrate"         type="int" value="128000"/>  
    <!-- 0:TYPE_TOF, 1:TYPE_TRIANGLE, 2:TYPE_TOF_NET -->
    <param name="lidar_type"       type="int" value="1"/>  
    <!-- 0:YDLIDAR_TYPE_SERIAL, 1:YDLIDAR_TYPE_TCP -->
    <param name="device_type"         type="int" value="0"/>  
    <param name="sample_rate"         type="int" value="5"/>  
    <param name="abnormal_check_count"         type="int" value="4"/>  

    <!-- bool property -->
    <param name="resolution_fixed"    type="bool"   value="true"/>
    <param name="auto_reconnect"    type="bool"   value="true"/>
    <param name="reversion"    type="bool"   value="false"/>
    <param name="inverted"    type="bool"   value="true"/>
    <param name="isSingleChannel"    type="bool"   value="false"/>
    <param name="intensity"    type="bool"   value="false"/>
    <param name="support_motor_dtr"    type="bool"   value="true"/>
    <param name="invalid_range_is_inf"    type="bool"   value="false"/>
    <param name="point_cloud_preservative"    type="bool"   value="false"/>

    <!-- float property -->
    <param name="angle_min"    type="double" value="-180" />
    <param name="angle_max"    type="double" value="180" />
    <param name="range_min"    type="double" value="0.1" />
    <param name="range_max"    type="double" value="12.0" />
    <!-- frequency is invalid, External PWM control speed -->
    <param name="frequency"    type="double" value="10.0"/>
  </node>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser4"
    args="0.0 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 /base_footprint /laser_frame 40" />
</launch>
```

mapping.rviz:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping">
    <param name="base_frame" value="base_link"/>
    <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
    <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
    <param name="map_update_interval" value="5.0"/>
    <param name="maxUrange" value="10.0"/>
    <param name="maxRange" value="12.0"/>
    <param name="sigma" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="kernelSize" value="1"/>
    <param name="lstep" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="astep" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="iterations" value="5"/>
    <param name="lsigma" value="0.075"/>
    <param name="ogain" value="3.0"/>
    <param name="lskip" value="0"/>
    <param name="minimumScore" value="50.0"/>
    <param name="srr" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="srt" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="str" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="stt" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="linearUpdate" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="angularUpdate" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="temporalUpdate" value="-1.0"/>
    <param name="resampleThreshold" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="particles" value="30"/>
    <param name="xmin" value="-50.0"/>
    <param name="ymin" value="-50.0"/>
    <param name="xmax" value="50.0"/>
    <param name="ymax" value="50.0"/>
    <param name="delta" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="llsamplerange" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="llsamplestep" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="lasamplerange" value="0.005"/>
    <param name="lasamplestep" value="0.005"/>
  </node>

  <!-- Display for Laser Scan -->
  <node name="laser_scan_display" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find rviz)/config/laser_scan.rviz" />

  <!-- Display for Map -->
  <node name="map_display" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find rviz)/config/navigation.rviz" />
</launch>
```

However, when I run roslaunch lidar lidar_gmapping.launch and add the display panel and the map visualization to the Rviz window that is opened, in the Global Status, there's a warning that says "no TF data" and in the map there's also a warning that says "no map received". Why is this happening?

**Extra information**

Output of roslaunch lidar lidar_gmapping.launch:

```
... logging to /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/f2b56a54-ce5c-11ee-ae1a-2bc73f30bdf2/roslaunch-ubuntu-4561.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://192.168.1.53:43169/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.16.0
 * /slam_gmapping/angularUpdate: 0.5
 * /slam_gmapping/astep: 0.05
 * /slam_gmapping/delta: 0.05
 * /slam_gmapping/iterations: 5
 * /slam_gmapping/kernelSize: 1
 * /slam_gmapping/lasamplerange: 0.005
 * /slam_gmapping/lasamplestep: 0.005
 * /slam_gmapping/linearUpdate: 1.0
 * /slam_gmapping/llsamplerange: 0.01
 * /slam_gmapping/llsamplestep: 0.01
 * /slam_gmapping/lsigma: 0.075
 * /slam_gmapping/lskip: 0
 * /slam_gmapping/lstep: 0.05
 * /slam_gmapping/map_update_interval: 5.0
 * /slam_gmapping/maxUrange: 16.0
 * /slam_gmapping/ogain: 3.0
 * /slam_gmapping/particles: 30
 * /slam_gmapping/resampleThreshold: 0.5
 * /slam_gmapping/sigma: 0.05
 * /slam_gmapping/srr: 0.1
 * /slam_gmapping/srt: 0.2
 * /slam_gmapping/str: 0.1
 * /slam_gmapping/stt: 0.2
 * /slam_gmapping/temporalUpdate: 3.0
 * /slam_gmapping/xmax: 50.0
 * /slam_gmapping/xmin: -50.0
 * /slam_gmapping/ymax: 50.0
 * /slam_gmapping/ymin: -50.0
 * /use_sim_time: True
 * /ydlidar_lidar_publisher/abnormal_check_count: 4
 * /ydlidar_lidar_publisher/angle_max: 180.0
 * /ydlidar_lidar_publisher/angle_min: -180.0
 * /ydlidar_lidar_publisher/auto_reconnect: True
 * /ydlidar_lidar_publisher/baudrate: 128000
 * /ydlidar_lidar_publisher/device_type: 0
 * /ydlidar_lidar_publisher/frame_id: laser
 * /ydlidar_lidar_publisher/frequency: 10.0
 * /ydlidar_lidar_publisher/ignore_array: 
 * /ydlidar_lidar_publisher/intensity: False
 * /ydlidar_lidar_publisher/invalid_range_is_inf: False
 * /ydlidar_lidar_publisher/inverted: True
 * /ydlidar_lidar_publisher/isSingleChannel: False
 * /ydlidar_lidar_publisher/lidar_type: 1
 * /ydlidar_lidar_publisher/point_cloud_preservative: False
 * /ydlidar_lidar_publisher/port: /dev/ydlidar
 * /ydlidar_lidar_publisher/range_max: 12.0
 * /ydlidar_lidar_publisher/range_min: 0.1
 * /ydlidar_lidar_publisher/resolution_fixed: True
 * /ydlidar_lidar_publisher/reversion: False
 * /ydlidar_lidar_publisher/sample_rate: 5
 * /ydlidar_lidar_publisher/support_motor_dtr: True

NODES
  /
    base_link_to_laser4 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    rviz (rviz/rviz)
    slam_gmapping (gmapping/slam_gmapping)
    ydlidar_lidar_publisher (ydlidar_ros_driver/ydlidar_ros_driver_node)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.53:11311/

process[slam_gmapping-1]: started with pid [4575]
process[ydlidar_lidar_publisher-2]: started with pid [4576]
process[base_link_to_laser4-3]: started with pid [4577]
[ INFO] [1708263246.713349137]: YDLIDAR ROS Driver Version: 1.0.2
process[rviz-4]: started with pid [4586]
[YDLIDAR] SDK initializing
[YDLIDAR] SDK has been initialized
[YDLIDAR] SDK Version: 1.1.21
[YDLIDAR] Lidar successfully connected [/dev/ydlidar:128000]
[YDLIDAR] Lidar running correctly! The health status: good
[YDLIDAR] Baseplate device info
Firmware version: 1.10
Hardware version: 1
Model: X4
Serial: 2021090300020786
[YDLIDAR] Lidar init success, Elapsed time 717 ms
[YDLIDAR] Start to getting intensity flag
[YDLIDAR] End to getting intensity flag
[YDLIDAR] Create thread 0x7B725170
[YDLIDAR] Successed to start scan mode, Elapsed time 4576 ms
[YDLIDAR] Fixed Size: 505
[YDLIDAR] Sample Rate: 5.00K
[YDLIDAR] Successed to check the lidar, Elapsed time 0 ms
[YDLIDAR] Now lidar is scanning...
```

Also, rostopic echo /map (or /tf or /clock) outputs this:

```
WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active.
Is /clock being published?
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is pretty descriptive: "simulation time is active" is at least the starting point of your error. Based on the launch files posted, it appears that the issue would be in the slam_gmapping_pr2 launch file - I'd suggest looking into what settings that launch file has set and getting "use_sim_time" to be set to false (since you do not want simulation time when using live sensor data)

Comment: One way I've found myself in a similar situation was trying out the launch files from a package, one of which set a use_sim_time rosparam. This went away upon restarting my roscore instance, clearing the params...

Comment: Thanks! That solved the global status error, but I still can't get information from the /map topic...